# Elastic search data upload

Tags: elasticsearch, import

I have an index with mapping as below and I need to load values to name_1 field. Anybody knows what command in elastic would do such thing?

```
{
"universitiesel": {
  "mappings": {
   "Universitiesel": {
     "properties": {
       "name": {
        "type": "text",
          "fields": {
           "keyword": {
           "type": "keyword",
           "ignore_above": 256
         }
        }
      },
        "name_1": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
        "name_2": {
        "type": "text"
      }
     }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: also - what format data should be? json? csv with only a column of values in it?

Comment: ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html , post again if you face issue and what you tried

Comment: @RishabhDugar as I understand, it only shows how to update values by typing them, I want to upload entire csv file instead of typing line by line. Thanks!

Comment: do you know how to do it with BULK API?

Answer (score 0):

Ref

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' -XPOST 'localhost:9200/shakespeare/doc/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @shakespeare_6.0.json
```

Source : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-load-dataset.html

Comment: ok, thanks for your help, appreciate it. I've found this one as well previously. Anyway, my colleague just did it by update by query. Thank you anyway!